# Правильная верстка html

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет!
Ставил верстку на сайт, и в шаблоне есть табличный элемент, но свертсанный div-ми.

```html
<div>
  <div>текст1</div >
  <div>текст2</div>
  <div class="last">текст3</div><a>выбрать</a>
</div>
```

Если перед последним элементом "a" и "div - last" есть пробел, то элемент "a" съезжает на следующую строку. Если пробела нет, то все хорошо.
На сколько это правильно? Приведите пожалуйста доводы.
п.с. Нажимая на кнопку "выбрать" отправляется ajax запрос.

Comment: `display: table` стоит?

Comment: Почему разметка не прикреплена? Почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Висящий инлайновый элемент, вне контекста не очень правильно

Comment: Пример таблицы для вашей разметки - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7ewhqvrp/

Comment: В этом и вопрос. Почему это не правильно?

Comment: Разметка не нужна. Суть в другом

Comment: Это правильно, и валидно. Но так лучше не делать, инлайновые елементы лучше не распологать рядом с блочными

Comment: Вот бы мне аргументировать почему этого нельзя делать((

Comment: Можно, просто вам неудобно будет, при ресайзе верстка поедет